# Intermediate JavaScript: assign a function with its parameter to a variable and execute later

Tags: javascript

I have a function in JavaScript:

```
function alertMe($a)
{
   alert($a);
}
```

Which I can execute like this: `alertMe("Hello");`

I want to do is assign `alertMe("Hello")` with the `"Hello"` parameter to a variable `$func`, and be able to execute this later by doing something like `$func();`.

Comment: look at the answer for code now

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would like to add the comment as answer

#### Code

```
//define the function
function alertMe(a) {
    //return the wrapped function
    return function () {
        alert(a);
    }
}
//declare the variable
var z = alertMe("Hello");
//invoke now
z();
```

Comment: This is using the concept of closure, I suppose.

Comment: @airnet I wouldn't call these closures, these are sort of late bound calls. closaure execute immediately without you invoking them sort of like this `(function(a){alert(a);})("HelloWorld");`

Answer (score 7):

Just build the function you need and store it in a variable:

```
var func = function() { alertMe("Hello") };
// and later...
func();
```

You could even make a function to build your functions if you wanted to vary the string:

```
function buildIt(message) {
    return function() { alertMe(message) };
}

var func1 = buildIt("Hello");
var func2 = buildIt("Pancakes");
// And later...
func1(); // says "Hello"
func2(); // says "Pancakes"
```

Comment: thanks guys, I wish I could accept both of your answers..:)
identical answers and what i was pretty much looking for

Answer (score -4):

You should use eval to execute saved function. For example:

```
var func = "alertMe('Hello')";
eval(func);
```

Comment: ...and a pointed tail. The use of eval is potentially unsafe and in this case, a downright dirty hack!